# How elasticsearch snapshot restore works on cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, restore, backup-strategies

I am having a ES cluster with 10 nodes having 2 master node. Each node having approx 500 GB of data. I would like to have backup of the whole cluster. Which would be the best possible way to do the same.
I have gone through the snapshot and restore API provided by Elasticsearch but the question is taking snapshot of huge amount of data in cluster and storing it to S3 would have more operational cost.

And for restore method, How the data can be restored from S3 to existing cluster having some existing data? Does the existing data on all nodes needs to be deleted before restore?

Does running a restore on master node will automatically start restoring the data on all 10 nodes? How does it is going to distribute the data on all nodes?

Any help would be appreciable.